# Detect Moire Pattern in an image - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, opencv

Is there any way to find Moire Patter in an image I can use in my iOS app using Swift and maybe OpenCV?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do show the code that you have tried so far

Comment: Bro I don't have any code. I need a way/algo to start from.

Comment: I bet here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/fast_fourier_transforms/halftone_descreening_with_2d_fast_fourier_transform is what you actually need

Answer (score 1):

You can find Moire Pattern in [Fourier transformed](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_transforms/py_fourier_transform/py_fourier_transform.html) image.

If you want to remove it, apply median filter and inverse Fourier transform.

See [this](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1701/1701.09037.pdf) paper.

Comment: Yeah I saw the paper but I will look into Fourier transformed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a cutting edge solution, then finding the Fourier transform is not the solution for you. It will eat up a lot of computing resources on the mobile as well. Instead, let the deep learning find the Fourier transform for you.
I have tried both the solutions on iOS:

1. Thresholding on the frequencies after the transform
2. Convolutional Neural Network based classifier

You will be surprised at the results using CNN.
Refer to this paper, https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8628746/

Comment: Is it your paper by the link? Is it available somewhere for download for free?

Comment: From my experience any inference by neural network on iOS takes at least 10 times more time/power than Fourier transform. Yes, Fourier transform is compute intensive. But CNNs are even more compute intensive.